# How can I install psi4 in a docker container with jupyter environment?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I tried to install [psi4](https://anaconda.org/psi4/psi4) to do a quantum chemistry calculation in the [jupyter/minimal-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/minimal-notebook) container.

However, as shown in the code block below, I could not install it due to `UnsatisfiableError`.

```sh
(base) jovyan@17285cef33b0:~/work$ conda create -n psi4 python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

....
(ellipsis)

(base) jovyan@17285cef33b0:~/work$ conda activate psi4

(psi4) jovyan@17285cef33b0:~/work$ conda install psi4 -c psi4
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

(psi4) jovyan@17285cef33b0:~/work$
```

It did not show what was not satisfied.

I don't want to use anaconda because I need to pay for commercial use of anaconda, and I want to use conda-forge as the environment to run psi4. I also want to use docker because I want to have the same conditions to run the program.

Do you have any good ideas to solve this error?
Or is there any environment that can fulfill my wishes?

My environment is Windows 10 and I am using Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was deleted because I just pasted the my blog post link. I extract the main steps of how to build from the my blog post and describe it.

I built and installed Psi4 on a docker container by myself. I wrote a post on my blog about how to do that. Please see the following blog post for more details.

https://solkul.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/04/23/002237

Here are the main steps on how to build it.

Basically, you can build it according to this [Psi4 documentation](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/build_planning.html).

## 1. Clone Psi4 repository

Clone the Psi4 repository.

```sh
(base) root$ git clone https://github.com/psi4/psi4.git
(base) root$ cd psi4
```

## 2. Create new conda environment

Start bash as root. Psi4 only supports until python 3.7, so I should create a conda environment for python 3.7.

```sh
(base) root$ conda create -n quantum python=3.7
(base) root$ conda activate quantum
(quantum) root$
```

## 3. Install the packages needed to build

Type the following command to install the packages required for the build. [Psi4 documentation](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/build_planning.html#faq-coredepend) lists tools and dependencies required for the build.

```sh
(quantum) root$ apt-get update
(quantum) root$ apt-get install -y build-essential cmake clang libssl-dev
(quantum) root$ apt-get install -y libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
(quantum) root$ conda install -y numpy networkx pint pydantic
(quantum) root$ apt-get install -y libmpfr-dev libeigen3-dev
```

## 4. Buid and install

It's time to build! Type the following command to Configure and Generate to build.

```sh
(quantum) root /psi4$ mkdir build
(quantum) root /psi4$ cd build
(quantum) root /psi4/build$ cmake ..
```

Let's build!

```sh
(quantum) root /psi4/build$ make -j`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
```

This build takes several hours.

After build is complete, type the following command to install it.

```sh
(quantum) root /psi4/build$ make install
```

## 5. Append `lib` of install directry to the python import path

In the default configuration, the binaries, includes, libraries, etc. should be installed in `/usr/local/psi4`. In order to use Psi4 as python module, it is needed to append `/usr/local/psi4/lib` to the python import path. You should also use Psi4 in the quantum environment, which I just created as the python 3.7 environment. You can do this by appending the directry to `sys.path` each time as follows.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("usr/local/psi4/lib")
```

From now, you can import Psi4.

```py
import psi4
```